# How to get title/item from response.body (HTTP - JSON)

Tags: json, flutter, dart, http, response

### I want to pull certain headers and items under the headers as string data from the JSON.

```
Map dataSignUpEmployeer = {
  'corporationName': employeer.getCorporationName(),
  'webSiteName': employeer.getWebSiteName(),
  'email': employeer.getEmail(),
  'password': employeer.getPassword(),
};

String bodySignUpEmployeer = json.encode(dataSignUpEmployeer);

postDataSignUpEmployeer() async {
  final response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(urlSignUp),
    headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    body: bodySignUpEmployeer,
  );
  return response.body;
}
```

> response.body return JSON

Eesponse.body's return:
[image]
Please help me in any way.

Comment: this link can help you [json response parsing](https://medium.flutterdevs.com/parsing-complex-json-in-flutter-b7f991611d3e)

Answer (score 0):

your code is working as well i see so i think you wrong in a part of your code for get the **success: true** from your **response body** so maybe you need to **authorize** your user in header of post method with **Token**. to get back success true and get all of each user data. any way we should see your api url.

Comment: i want to only pull data under header. Data comes from response.body
how to do this in dart